# How to set root URL in Metro bundler with Expo

Tags: react-native, expo, metro-bundler

I'm building a React Native app with Expo with web support. I plan to host the web version on a website in a subfolder, e.g.

`http://somewebsite/myapp/`

I build the web version with Metro bundler, using this command:

`npx expo export -p web`

Then, I upload files from the `dist` dir to the `myapp` folder on the website. However, the app doesn't start, and shows this error in console:

`http://somewebsite/bundles/web-cba49510376d833ebedca732d1e69545.js 404 Not Found`

I tried setting `projectRoot` in `metro.config.js`. That didn't have any effect.

How can I tell the Metro bundler to look for files in `http://somewebsite/myapp/` instead?